# sp_executesql causing incorrect syntax error in SQL Server 2008 R2 when parameterized

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this table:

```
╔═════╦════════╦════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ drn ║ RecNum ║ Name           ║     Value        ║
╠═════╬════════╬════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 1   ║ 1      ║ ad1_pk         ║ 1                ║
║ 2   ║ 1      ║ ad1_address1   ║ P.O. Box 5036    ║
║ 3   ║ 1      ║ ad1_address2   ║ NULL             ║
║ 4   ║ 1      ║ ad1_address3   ║ NULL             ║
║ 5   ║ 1      ║ ad1_ctyfk      ║ 56               ║
║ 6   ║ 1      ║ ad1_postalcode ║ 80155-5036       ║
║ 7   ║ 1      ║ ad1_active     ║ Y                ║
║ 8   ║ 1      ║ ad1_irstat     ║ A                ║
║ 9   ║ 1      ║ ad1_irdata     ║ NULL             ║
║ 10  ║ 1      ║ ad1_at1fk      ║ 1                ║
║ 1   ║ 2      ║ ad1_pk         ║ 2                ║
║ 2   ║ 2      ║ ad1_address1   ║ 1871 S. Broadway ║
║ 3   ║ 2      ║ ad1_address2   ║ NULL             ║
║ 4   ║ 2      ║ ad1_address3   ║ NULL             ║
║ 5   ║ 2      ║ ad1_ctyfk      ║ 1                ║
║ 6   ║ 2      ║ ad1_postalcode ║ 80210            ║
║ 7   ║ 2      ║ ad1_active     ║ Y                ║
║ 8   ║ 2      ║ ad1_irstat     ║ A                ║
║ 9   ║ 2      ║ ad1_irdata     ║ NULL             ║
║ 10  ║ 2      ║ ad1_at1fk      ║ 1                ║
╚═════╩════════╩════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

I am creating the pivot using this query:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @var = STUFF((select ',' + name from (select name from temp where recnum = 1) 
as abc for xml path('')),1,1,'')

set @sql = 'select * from temp
pivot(max(value) for name in (' + @var + ')) as pvt'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

This query works fine. I just read on google about SQL injection and came to know that my above query if added in stored procedure will have a SQL injection vulnerability.

So I modified the query to this SQL but I am getting error:

> "Incorrect syntax near '@var".

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @var = STUFF((select ',' + name from (select name from temp where recnum = 1) 
as abc for xml path('')),1,1,'')

set @sql = 'select * from temp
pivot(max(value) for name in ( @var )) as pvt'

exec sp_executesql @sql,N'@var nvarchar(max)',@var
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong in my second query in which I tried to parameterize it?

Comment: You can parametrize variables, not expressions...

Comment: Select , name isn't a valid syntax

Comment: You cannot do "IN ( \@var )", because what is inside the parens needs to be literal, and \@var will not auto-expand to its contents.  So this is not the way to get around your potential SQL injection issue.

Comment: @pmbAustin That's true, but this is for a PIVOT expression.  The IN isn't a list of values.  It's a list of field headings.  It's an entirely different beast.  This query can't be parameterized in this manner.

Comment: have you tried printing @var out to make sure its being created as expected?

Comment: Do you have any control over what data gets into the `Name` column of your table?  If so, then you should be able to prevent the possibility SQL Injection attacks by preventing SQL injection-type code from going into the table in the first place.  (Thus preventing the need to worry about your dynamic Pivot query.)  Perhaps I'm wrong, but it seems to me that you should have some control over the names of your parameters.

Comment: This has nothing to do with sp_executesql.  If you print out `@sql`, and replace `@var` with some string value, you will see your PIVOT statement is incorrect, and cannot even execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is, your column list in the outer SELECT statement needs to match the values in the IN statement, which it does not.  You have `select *`, which is incorrect (echoing what @Bacon said).  Without knowing exactly what you want, this is how your TSQL should look work:

```
select [1] as col1, [2] as col2, [3] as col3 
from (
  select Name, [Value]
  from temp) p
  pivot(
    max([Value]) for Name in ( [1], [2], [3] )
  ) as pvt
;
```

You can read more about PIVOT [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).